How to understand tensor product?
Can I conceptualize tensor product as a product between matrices of matrices? So could I apply the regular Matrix multiplication between rows and columns of matrices (made of matrices instead of scalars), and then when the elements I'm going to multiply are the submatrices apply recursively the algorithm, or the regular matrix multiplication if I went down enough in the hierarchy to find the bidimensional matrices?.
Thanks

It should be straightforward to try your concepts on a few $2\times 2$ matrices. Show some attempts.
